# Should aria-label's be capitalized?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, capitalization

I've seen some examples and documentation that capitalizes the first word of aria labels. Why is this? What if you have two words?

Comment: aria label can be in lowercase as well, please check this link - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria/

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter if it's sentence case, camel case, or all lowercase.  Most screen readers will say it the same.  But don't make the label all caps because that can change the inflection of the screen reader voice and can cause some words to be read as separate characters.  For example, "MY LABEL" could be potentially be pronunced as "em why el a be ee el".

Answer (score 2):

I was using [ChromeVox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromevox-classic-extensi/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en) to test this behaviour and the screen reader in all the three cases is reading using the same pronunciation and in the same speed, i.e. for these examples:

1. THIS IS MY TEXT
2. This Is My Text
3. this is my text

Haven't noticed any difference.